# Python: Delete lists with same elements but in different order

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that calculates quadruplets (a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3). With my current code i get 8 answers within the domain of [1, 15], but as you'll see by the output, the answers are all the same but the order is switched around. My question is: how can i filter out the duplicates and just get one answer? (Sorry if i caused you a heart attack with my messy code)

Code:

```
interval = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
solutions = []

for a in interval:
    for b in interval:
        for c in interval:
            for d in interval:
                if a != c and b !=d:
                    if a != d and b != c:
                        if a**3+b**3 == c**3+d**3:
                            temp = [a, b, c, d]
                            solutions.append(temp)
                            
print(solutions)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 12, 9, 10], [1, 12, 10, 9], [9, 10, 1, 12], [9, 10, 12, 1], [10, 9, 1, 12], [10, 9, 12, 1], [12, 1, 9, 10], [12, 1, 10, 9]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't write a full answer right now, but I'm going to point you to [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations); you can collapse four loops into one, drop two of three `if` checks (when `interval` is known to not have repeats), and get unique combinations, order-insensitive. It'll be *dramatically* faster than any solution that generates all the duplicates, then dedupes in postprocessing.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That depends, if OP forgot add checks for `a != b and c != d` you are right but if that is not the desired behaviour, `combinations` would not be what OP needs.

Comment: The aforementioned code: `for a, b, c, d in itertools.combinations(range(1, 15), 4):`

Answer (score 6):

As ShadowRanger mentioned in the comments, `itertools.combinations` is the tool to use:

```
from itertools import combinations
solutions = []
for (a,b),(c,d) in combinations(combinations(range(1,16),2),2):
    if a**3 + b**3 == c**3 + d**3:
        solutions.append((a,b,c,d))
print(solutions)
```

prints `[(1, 12, 9, 10)]`

Comment: +1, I was writing up this exact solution, with one minor difference, I think it'd be best to keep `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` separate in the solution: `solutions.append(((a, b), (c, d)))`

Comment: What is your feeling on @Blckknght solution? I am pretty sure it is incorrect as it does not test all the possibilities, but I not in the ideal environment to put my finger on it. (I might be wrong though)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to produce ordered 4-tuples from your list with much less duplication. But it does present a new problem, that you don't actually want ordered values, since your equation can't possibly be satisfied with `a < b < c < d`, since you'd be adding up the cubes of the two smallest values which will always be smaller than the cubes of the two largest values.

That does lead us to a key insight. We never want to pair up the two largest and two smallest values from our four-tuple. Further, we don't even want to pair up the smaller of the first two values with the smaller of the second two values, because again, they cubes will always wind up smaller than the other pair. So we can just always pair up the largest value with the smallest value and pair up the two middle values. So if they're ordered (`a < b < c < d`), you want `a**3 + d**3` and `b**3 + c**3`. Here's how I'd do that in code:

```
import itertools as it

interval = range(1, 16)

results = [[a, d, b, c] for a, b, c, d in it.combinations(interval, 4)
                        if a**3 + d**3 == b**3 + c**3]
```

Comment: This is both correct and a very elegant solution, if `b == c` has to be false, which I am not yet convinced of, but there may be an obvious reason why that has to be the case that I am missing.

Comment: I suspect this solution is wrong, this only works here by chance. The 4-ways combinations does not yield all the possibilities, unlike the combination of combinations of @JohnColeman (1365 vs 5460).

Comment: @Jasminj I think it gives the correct answer but it is not correct and could fall on other conditions.

Comment: @mozway actually those combinations in John Coleman's answer are all ones that cannot satisfy the equation, because they have `{a, b} & {c, d}` which means they are of the form `x1 ** 3 + x2 ** 3 == x1 ** 3 + x3 ** 3` where all the xs are larger than 1, which would mean that `x2 == x3` , which means it could only ever generate trivial solutions of the form `a ** 3 + b ** 3 == a ** 3 + b ** 3`.

Comment: @Jasmijn OK thanks for the feedback, I'll check this again with a clear head.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can prove that given `a < b < c < d` you can't get any solution other than `a**3 + d**3 == b**3 + c**3`. The prove would go via these intermediate inequalities: `x < y => x**3 < y**3` and `w < x and y < z  =>  w+y < x+z`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add an order to your solutions. For example, according to your function, you can add this line to your conditions:

```
if a < b and c < d and a < c:
```

Then you only have:

```
Output : [[1, 12, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that involves `itertools.product` and sets of sets of sets:

```
from itertools import product

interval = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
solutions = set()

for a, b, c, d in product(interval, repeat=4):
    if a != c and b != d and a != d and b != c:
        if a ** 3 + b ** 3 == c ** 3 + d ** 3:
            left_side = frozenset({a, b})
            right_side = frozenset({c, d})
            equality = frozenset({left_side, right_side})
            solutions.add(equality)

print(solutions)
```

This makes use of the fact that `a` and `b` can be swapped without affecting the equality, and the same goes for `c` and `d`, and `(a, b)` can be swapped with `(c, d)`.